# Como faço para criar um accordion simples com multilinha com Java e Totalcross?

Tags: java, totalcross

Olhei no exemplo deles no github mas mostram como fazer uma especie de input (um multiedit) para a pessoa digitar e não uma label com varias linhas.

[image: Veja como ficou o meu:]

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque você está colocando o texto como legenda (`.caption`), tenta com o código abaixo.

```
public class AccordionSample extends MainWindow{

    public AccordionSample(){
        setUIStyle(Settings.MATERIAL_UI);
    }

    public void initUI(){
        AccordionContainer.Group gr = new AccordionContainer.Group();
        AccordionContainer ac[] = new AccordionContainer[5];
        Label lb = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \nadipiscing elit. Vivamus pellentesque massa \nnon magna maximus fermentum."
                + " \nNunc condimentum tempor odio, in dictum \nneque sollicitudin sit amet. Sed ut venenatis \nsem."
                + " \nMorbi sagittis purus fringilla, suscipit lorem \nquis, cursus ipsum. Donec sodales rutrum \nrisus, ac sagittis est laoreet ac. "
                + "\nCurabitur egestas leo.");

        ac[0] = new AccordionContainer(gr);
        ac[0].setFont(font.asBold());

        add(ac[0],LEFT+10,CENTER,PARENTSIZE+95,PARENTSIZE+43);
        ac[0].setBackForeColors(0X757575, 0Xffffff);
        ac[0].add(ac[0].new Caption("Any Text:"), LEFT+5, TOP, FILL, PREFERRED);
        ac[0].add(lb,LEFT+5,TOP+22,FILL,PREFERRED);
    }
}
```

[image: Resultado do código acima]